# Find the parameters a and b such that the function is continuous at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\cos(x+a) & x<0 \\
e^{(x+b)^2} & x \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

a) Find $a$ and $b$ such that the function is continuous at $x=0$.

So what I did:

$$ \cos(0+a) = e^{b^2} \quad\text{(eq1)}$$

and then I equated their derivatives:

$$ -\sin(a) = 2b e^{b^2} \quad\text{(eq2)}$$

and so the final equation became:

$$ \tan (a) = -2b. $$

What do I do after this?

---

Also part b was show that the equation $e^x = 2 + \cos x$ has a unique solution. I graphed the equation and it is true, but how do I show it otherwise?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a) it looks like you can simply take $a = 0$ and $b = 0$.

For part (b) observe that $1 \le 2 + \cos x \le 3$ for all $x$ and that $1 \le e^x \le 3$ only for $x \in [0, \log 3]$. On that interval $e^x$ is increasing and $2 + \cos x$ is decreasing so $e^x - (2 + \cos x)$ is increasing. Can you have an increasing function cross the $x$-axis more than once? Is there a theorem that says that gives a condition for when a function crosses the $x$-axis?

Comment: Okay so by the intermediate value theorem (a function which starts below the x-axis and finishes above must cross the x-axis) so that means it only crosses once. Also since it is an increasing exponential function we can say it is an one-to-one function which gives us an unique solution.

Comment: @Zeemz97 Careful, you wrote that the IVT means that it "only crosses once". The IVT shows that it crosses and the fact that it is increasing means that it can't cross at multiple points (you should try showing this from the definition of increasing: $x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)$).